# What is the oldest manuscript of Torah Shebaal Peh?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, text, oral-torah, manuscripts

We don't have (and more's the pity!) R' Yehudah Hanassi's autograph copy of the Mishnah (well, okay, it's a controversial issue whether he actually wrote it or only arranged it orally), or Ravina and Rav Ashi's of the Gemara, etc.

But what is the oldest known manuscript of the Mishnah, Gemara, Mechilta, or any other part of Torah Shebaal Peh? (Or perhaps there are manuscripts of Geonic writings - responsa, Halachos Gedolos, or whatever - that predate any known copies of the foundational texts?)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70808

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The oldest written Torah Sheb'al Peh (though not exactly a manuscript) would seem to be the recently-discovered mosaic of the ancient shul in Beit Shaan. The Hebrew Wikipedia article about that shul (which was destroyed 1300 years ago, and existed a few hundred before that) can be found [at this link](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C#.D7.A8.D7.97.D7.95.D7.91). Here is their image of the mosaic:

[image: Old, damaged mosaic depicting about 30 lines of Hebrew text]

The text is similar to passages in Yerushalmi Sheviis. An analysis of this text can be found in Teshuvos Mishnas Yosef 1:51, and at the end of Kaftor Vaferach vol. 1 (in the 3-volume edition).

Comment: Wow, what an old Wikipedia article! 1300 years, you say?

Comment: Context, @SethJ, context! (But I agree that misplaced modifiers are good for a laugh sometimes. :)

Comment: English wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_of_Rehob

Comment: I'm curious, is the Kaftor v'Perach discussing this actual inscription because he saw it, or is he just talking about the same thing because he is talking about Shviit or something?

Answer (score 12):

The oldest actual manuscript fragment appears to be the Cairo Genizah scroll fragment in the Cambridge University Library Genizah collection (which can be searched for ALL its wonderful things [here](http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/search?=&page=1)-try "Talmud" or "ketubah" or "Rashi" for starters) studied by Professor Shamma Friedman, containing the Bavli's Chullin 101a - 105a. Opinions to the exact date vary, from "at latest 7th century(600's CE)" to Dr. Stephan Reif's estimate of around 750 CE.  A picture and brief description of it is [here](http://tzvee.blogspot.com/2009/12/was-talmud-hullin-scroll-oldest-talmud.html) and Professor Friedman's full JSTOR article is [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1454821?sid=21105724200083&uid=3739696&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256).  You have to sign up to read the full article, but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Please also see:
An Early Fragment of "Avot de Rabbi Natan" from a Scroll
מרק ברגמן, Marc Bregman, An Early Fragment of "Avot de Rabbi Natan" from a Scroll / קטע קדום של אבות דרבי נתן מתוך מגילה, Tarbiẕ / תרביץ, כרך נב‎, חוברת ב‎ (טבת-אדר תשמ"ג), pp. 201-222
https://www.jstor.org/stable/23595970

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Arik and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting old Yerushalmi fragment from Leningrad:

A **Genizah Fragment** of Talmud Yerushalmi in the Antonin Collection of the Saltykov-Shchedrin Library in Leningrad on JSTOR
Abraham I. Katsh, A Genizah Fragment of Talmud Yerushalmi in the Antonin Collection of the Saltykov-Shchedrin Library in Leningrad, The Jewish Quarterly Review, New Series, Vol. 71, No. 3 (Jan., **1981**), pp. 181-184
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1454392