# In the Talmud, how is the Tetragrammaton rendered?

Tags: talmud-gemara, shemos-sacred-names

Did the authors of the Talmud substitute the Tetragrammaton with something else?

I'm wondering if the practice extant in the LXX of using a title other than the Tetragrammaton where the name appears in the scripture. IE: If they quote a scripture containing the name do they instead say something equivalent to "the LORD"? Or do they use the Tetragrammaton as it is in the Hebrew?

Comment: To VTCers: Perhaps the basis for asking the question might be unclear, but I think the question itself is very well presented. I'm not sure why the unclear close reason would apply here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Babylonian Talmud has both Aramaic and Hebrew in it. In the handwritten versions which I reviewed, the 4 letter name of hashem is replaced with the [yod](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32156/holiness-status-of-yod-yod)-yod.

You can see this in the quotes from the bible used on Tractate B'rachot, 6A. The printed version I have replaces the 4 letter name with the Hey-apostrophe.

From the Munich Codex of 1342

http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/collections/jewish-collection/Talmud/Pages/default.aspx?IsByManuscript=False&Im_Ms=1628&Fr_Co=4&Fr_Tr=01&Pe_code=006&Mi_code=02&Li_code=-1

6th line up from the bottom of the thinner lines next to the punch-out quote, second to last word.

http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/collections/jewish-collection/Talmud/Pages/default.aspx?IsByManuscript=False&Im_Ms=1976&Fr_Co=4&Fr_Tr=01&Pe_code=006&Mi_code=02&Li_code=-1

9th line down, second to last word.

Comment: When and where are those written versions from? In all likelihood whatever was the popular local contemporary mark was used, and hence nothing can be drawn about what was used in the days of the Talmud's authors

Comment: rosends, I upvoted and received this as an answer but I would appreciate it if you would address Double AA's comment. Thanks.

Comment: @WoundedEgo on this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/what-is-the-oldest-manuscript-of-torah-shebaal-peh there is an image of a text/mosaic which dates back, maybe as early as approximately 330 CE but I don't know if that would be any more the reflection of the "authors" than something else. It might just be the convention of the local artist who made it.

Comment: The substitution for the 4-letter Name probably varies from edition to edition. Some prints have יי. Some prints have ה or ד. Some prints scrap the Name entirely and replace it with הקדוש ברוך הוא or ריבונו של עולם.