# Was the Talmud available in written form, partially or fully, before the 7th century?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

was the Talmud available in written form partially or fully before the 7th century?

or just was transmitted orally?

Comment: It was written, but many places could not afford a copy or scribe. So depends where.

Comment: thank you N.T ...any quotes proves ,that mention those written examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the oldest manuscript of Torah Shebaal Peh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/what-is-the-oldest-manuscript-of-torah-shebaal-peh)

Comment: Also see this manuscript: https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-TS-00016-00320/1

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud is literally just the written oral torah, so the question is whether or not the talmud existed yet. It did.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud#History